# One of JQuery functions is not executed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am implementing a star rating system with JQuery. 
I am sharing some part of code below. The second jquery function is working fine(action to perform on click), but the first one (on mouseover) is not working at all. As if the code block does not exist. No errors or anything on the console, if I remove the codeblock about mouseover, nothing changes. So looks like that part is not executed as at all. 
I tried to change the order of the scripts but didn't change anything.
What am I doing wrong?

**This is the relevant part of the HTML:**

```
                    <section class='rating-widget'>
                    <div class='rating-stars'>
                      <ul id='stars<?=$row['id'];?>' >
                          <li class='star'   onclick="savePodcastId('<?=$row['id'];?>')"   title='Kötü'  data-value='1>'>
                          <i class='fa fa-star' style="font-size: 24px;"></i>
                        </li>
                        <li class='star'  onclick="savePodcastId('<?=$row['id'];?>')"  title='Eh' data-value='2'>
                          <i class='fa fa-star' style="font-size: 24px;"></i>
                        </li>
                        <li class='star' onclick="savePodcastId('<?=$row['id'];?>')"  title='İyi' data-value='3'>
                          <i class='fa fa-star' style="font-size: 24px;"></i>
                        </li>
                        <li class='star'  onclick="savePodcastId('<?=$row['id'];?>')"  title='Çok İyi' data-value='4'>
                          <i class='fa fa-star' style="font-size: 24px;"></i>
                        </li>
                        <li class='star' onclick="savePodcastId('<?=$row['id'];?>')"  title='Harika' data-value='5'>
                          <i class='fa fa-star' style="font-size: 24px;"></i>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </section>
```

**This is the script:**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

  setDefaultRating();


    // hover
$('#stars li').on('mouseover', function(){
    var onStar = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10); // The star currently mouse on

    // Now highlight all the stars that's not after the current hovered star
    $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(e){
      if (e < onStar) {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
      }
      else {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
      }
    });

  }).on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).parent().children('li.star').each(function(e){
      $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
  });

   <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `podcasts` where populer=1" ;
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>

  /* 2. Action to perform on click */
  $('#stars<?=$row['id'];?> li').on('click', function(){
    var onStar = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10); // The star currently selected
    var stars = $(this).parent().children('li.star');

    for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).removeClass('selected');
    }

    for (i = 0; i < onStar; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).addClass('selected');
    }

    // JUST RESPONSE (Not needed)
    var ratingValue = parseInt($('#stars<?=$row['id'];?> li.selected').last().data('value'), 10);

    var podcastId = $("#podcastId").val();
    verify(ratingValue);


  });

        <?php  }?>

});
```

Comment: we'd need to see (a relevant sample of) the HTML to be sure what the problem might be. You can use the View Source feature in your browser to see the final HTML being generated by  PHP is.

Comment: But I can make a guess... since the second function generates a selector using `$('#stars<?=$row['id'];?>`, I would assume your HTML elements have IDs like `stars1`, `stars2`, `stars3` etc. Therefore `#stars` probably won't select anything because maybe there's no such element. unless you have another element with `id="stars"` which you defined separately? I can only guess...that's why we need to see the HTML.

Comment: Also, instead of using your loop to generate loads of identical code, why not just give all your stars elements the same class, and use a single jQuery handler to deal with them all, by selecting by class e.g. `$(".stars li")`?

Comment: I added the HTML part about stars, I am just copying an existing project here https://codepen.io/mmoradi08/pen/yLyYrGg I havent give much thought about it and I'm a newbie in coding

Comment: As commented above `$('#stars").length === 0` so there's nothing to assign the event handler to, so nothing happens (as you have witnessed).  Change `$('#stars li')` to `$("li.star")`

Comment: I changed it to "li.star" and it works now!!! A big thank you!!

Comment: Also, make sure your javascript code is not inside the php loop otherwise you'll generate multiple identical events which will slow down your page (or conflict with each other).

Comment: In the example above the second function is in the loop because I am fetching multiple items from db that must have separate ratings.. Don't know how else to do it..